# Add columns to each row of pandas dataframe

Tags: json, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe (df) that has columns 'ip', 'country', 'city'. This data frame df has a lot of rows (~ 50,000) which is same as distinct IPs. I want to do a 'whois' lookup for each of the IPs and get more attributes and add those attributes to the existing data frame df.

For eg, from the results of whois, I retrieve 'asn', 'asn_cidr', 'email', 'address' and 'adminName'.

Currently, this is what I am doing (sample code):

```
def f(ip):
    obj = IPWhois(ip, timeout = 10)
    if obj:
        results = obj.lookup_rdap(depth=1, retry_count=5, rate_limit_timeout=60)
    else:
        results = None
    return results


def ac(ip):
    obj = IPWhois(ip, timeout = 10)
    if obj:
        names = []
        results = obj.lookup_rdap(depth=1, retry_count=5, rate_limit_timeout=60)
        entities = results['entities']
        for e in entities:
            name = results['objects'][e]['contact']['name']
            names.append(name)
    return names


from ipwhois import IPWhois

df['adminName'] = df['ip'].map(lambda x: ac(x))
df['email']     = df['ip'].map(lambda x: email(x))
df['address']   = df['ip'].map(lambda x: address(x))
df['asn']       = df['ip'].map(lambda x: f(x)['asn'])
df['asn_cidr']  = df['ip'].map(lambda x: f(x)['asn_cidr'])
```

df['ip'] looks like this:

```
SS-MacBook-Pro:src SS$ python exRepList_0.21.py
0        46.4.123.15
1      222.136.71.19
2      27.254.67.157
3       37.48.125.51
4     153.194.72.226
5    116.117.253.243
6      91.200.12.111
7      60.173.82.156
8         60.28.1.43
9       36.72.228.72
Name: ip, dtype: object
SSs-MacBook-Pro:src SS$
```

Problem: The above code works. But, it makes a lot of redundant lookups to the same IP. For eg: to fill the adminName column, it gets all the 50000 IPs, gets their JSON objects, retrieves admin names, fills-in and then moves on to the next attribute. Again, for each 50000 Ips, does the same...
I want to do one lookup per IP, get the resulting JSON object, parse the json file for all necessary attributes, fill a row in a new data frame (or existing data frame), and move on to the next IP address. Something like: [not sure if this approach is efficient/nice...]

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    ip      = str(row['ip']).strip()
    obj     = IPWhois(ip)
    results = obj.lookup_rdap(depth=1)
    # Now, parse 'results' to get all the needed attributes.
```

Comment: .@user  Pandas can read JSON    http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html  Make one call get the JSON and parse it.  Its would be helpful to know what df['ip'] looks like.

Comment: .@user add to question please. And one results JSON,... add to question  other ppl may not read the comments.

Comment: added how df['ip'] looks like.

Comment: .@user you are on the right track with second process! The approach is IO efficient. Use it.